# How to access multiple DBs same time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me on below query which gives me file group space used and current space. I am not able to use the code below.

I want to execute the command in all DBs same time so I am using the `msforeachdb` option. Please correct me.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT 
    [TYPE] = A.TYPE_DESC
    ,[FILE_Name] = A.name
    ,[FILEGROUP_NAME] = fg.name
    ,[File_Location] = A.PHYSICAL_NAME
    ,[FILESIZE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0)
    ,[USEDSPACE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0 - ((SIZE/128.0) - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0))
    ,[FREESPACE_MB] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),A.SIZE/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0)
    ,[FREESPACE_%] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),((A.SIZE/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(A.NAME, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT)/128.0)/(A.SIZE/128.0))*100)
    ,[AutoGrow] = 'By ' + CASE is_percent_growth WHEN 0 THEN CAST(growth/128 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' MB -' 
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(growth AS VARCHAR(10)) + '% -' ELSE '' END 
        + CASE max_size WHEN 0 THEN 'DISABLED' WHEN -1 THEN ' Unrestricted' 
            ELSE ' Restricted to ' + CAST(max_size/(128*1024) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' GB' END 
        + CASE is_percent_growth WHEN 1 THEN ' [autogrowth by percent, BAD setting!]' ELSE '' END FROM sys.database_files A LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON A.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id  order by A.TYPE desc, A.NAME; '
```

Comment: You'll have to double the embeded single quote marks. Is there another specific error message thrown?

Answer (score 0):

you cant have multiple databases 'in use' at one time, as there are a lot of things which change between databases even within the same instance.

You can access databases outside of the currently accessed database like so:

```
USE [DB1]
SELECT * FROM [schema].[table]
SELECT * FROM [DB2].[schema].[table]
```

This will grab you the information from the active database[DB1], and then information from the other database [DB2] because you specified to go there to find it

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses [four part names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx#Anchor_0). To reference an object outside the current DB qualify the name more fully or create a [synonym](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx).

[USE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx#Anchor_2) provides security context and default for the optional parts in four part names.